# making cigarette smoke

Tags: smoke-simulation

[image]

im having lots of trouble replicating the thin and whispy smoke that comes out of a cigarette. nevermind the material but how do i do this? the particles arent compact enough which makes the smoke look to thick. ive tried tweaking with just about every setting but to no avail.

Comment: Hey, there is a different version of Blender with the Mantaflow branch, which is said to be a lot better at simulating smoke. Apart from that and I hate to say it, but googling helps a lot in this particular simulation, here for example is cigarette smoke + the .blend that produced it: https://vimeo.com/2287753

Comment: Use lower vorticity and play with the Density and Temperature difference. Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/smoke/types/domain.html